# Convert #hex to 0xFF-hex

Tags: hex

Why 0xFF0000ff is red, and #0000ff is blue? And how do I convert #0000ff into 0x, so it would work properly? I tried to add 0xFF in the beginning, but it results in unexpected (by me) behaviour

I am trying to implement this algorithm http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/wpfd8he1/

```
function getPixel(pixelData, x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= pixelData.width || y >= pixelData.height) {
    return -1;  // impossible color
  } else {
    return pixelData.data[y * pixelData.width + x];
  }
}

function floodFill(ctx, x, y, fillColor) {
  // read the pixels in the canvas
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  // make a Uint32Array view on the pixels so we can manipulate pixels
  // one 32bit value at a time instead of as 4 bytes per pixel
  const pixelData = {
    width: imageData.width,
    height: imageData.height,
    data: new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer),
  };

  // get the color we're filling
  const targetColor = getPixel(pixelData, x, y);

  // check we are actually filling a different color
  if (targetColor !== fillColor) {

    const pixelsToCheck = [x, y];
    while (pixelsToCheck.length > 0) {
      const y = pixelsToCheck.pop();
      const x = pixelsToCheck.pop();

      const currentColor = getPixel(pixelData, x, y);
      if (currentColor === targetColor) {
        pixelData.data[y * pixelData.width + x] = fillColor;
        pixelsToCheck.push(x + 1, y);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x - 1, y);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x, y + 1);
        pixelsToCheck.push(x, y - 1);
      }
    }

    // put the data back
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal colours follow the format [ `0x` ] [ `red`] [ `green`] [ `blue`] [ `transparency`].

 Conversely, hex 'codes' follow the format [ `#` ] [ `red`] [ `green`] [ `blue`] (with no transparency value listed).

Each colour is allocated 2 units between `0` and `F`. It does not matter whether the unit is lowercase or uppercase.

`0xFF0000ff` equates to the hex code `#FF0000` with `ff` (solid) transparency. Breaking this down we have [ `FF` (red) ] [ `00` (green) ] [ `00` (blue) ] -- solid red.

In order to covert any hex code to hexadecimal notation, you simply need to *prepend* `0x` and *append* the transparency value. Assuming the colour you want to convert is opaque, you simply need to append `ff`.

For example, to convert `#0000ff` (blue) to hex, you prepend `0x` and append `ff`, giving you `0x0000ffff`.

Comment: Then the algorithm above doesn't work :( I have spent two nights trying to implement this flood fill, but to no avail :(

Comment: 0x0000ffff does not paint blue (in the algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

0x hex colors are reversed from web hex codes. `#RRGGBBAA` for hex code would be `0xAABBGGRR`, where `AA` is alpha, `BB` is blue, `GG` is green, and `RR` is red.